# Update C# From HashSet to Try.Parse

Tags: c#, hashset, tryparse

The code works much better, thanks to the help I have been given here. Some of you suggested that I should use "TryParse", but I don't know how to use it properly in this code. Do you have any suggestions?

```
int i = 1;
while (set.Count < 10)
{
Console.Write("|Write number " + i + ": ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
while (!int.TryParse(input, out number))
{
 if (!set.Add(number)) //
{
Console.Write("Write a new unique number!");
}
else
{
i++;
}
```

Comment: Create the HashSet *before* you start the for-loop.

Comment: It would be better to use `int.TryParse` with user input.

Answer (score 4):

So you want ten numbers to be added, you can start with declaring the HashSet outside of your loop:

```
var numbers = new HashSet<int>();
```

In this case since you want your loop to continue until some condition satisfies, it's better to use a `while` loop:

```
int i = 1;
while(numbers.Count < 10) 
{
     Console.Write("|Write number " + i + ": ");
     int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     if(!numbers.Add(number))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("The number already exists, try again.");
     }
     else 
     {  
         i++;
     }
}
```

Inside of the loop we simply try to add the given number to `HashSet`, [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) method adds the number if it doesn't exist on the `HashSet` and returns `true`, otherwise it returns `false`.

This code does what you want but you might wanna consider some improvements like validating the user input to make sure it's a valid number. You can do this by using [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Think of [HashSet<int>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) as just being a set of integers. 
You can add, remove and search for integers.

```
HashSet<int> foundAlready = new HashSet<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (foundAlready.Contains(number))
    {
        // User has entered this number already - do something.
    }
    else
    {
        // First time for this number - do something else.
        foundAlready.Add(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, you instantiate objects of HashSet class in cycle.So you *recreate* set of answers after each one.
It's wrong. You should have **one** HashSet into which you should add items or test it whether it has specific item.

Basicaly, your code should be:

```
HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
int number;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    Console.Write("|Write number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    //try add to set
    if (set.Add(number)){
       //set doesn't contain such number, so number has been inserted
    }
    else
    {
      //set contains number
    }
}
```